# Smarty Template {foreachelse} postback if statement troubleshooting

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, smarty, postback

I'm probably making this harder than it actually is but...My error, no results! is displaying before my form is submitted. Is there a way in Smarty template to check for postback from the server?

```
{foreach from=$book item=row}
{$row.DESCRIPTION}
{foreachelse}
{if ($postback) == "thisvalue"}
Error, no results!
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

I tried this on my form (which didn't work either):

```
<input type="hidden" type="text" name="postback" value='thisvalue'>

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$postback = $_POST['postback'];
$tpl->assign("postback", $postback);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for a value in the post-data directly with `{$smarty.post.postback}`, which is equivalent to the PHP suberglobal `$_POST['postback']`. However, as [the Smarty documentation page for this feature](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.request) says:

> Although Smarty provides direct access to PHP super globals for convenience, it should be used with caution. Directly accessing super globals mixes underlying application code structure with templates. A good practice is to assign specific needed values to template vars.

In your case, you are presumably processing the "postback" (i.e. form submission) in some PHP code somewhere, and then passing the result of that processing to Smarty for display. It is that PHP code which should be determining if a form submission has occurred, and validating the input submitted (e.g. was the field left blank, or did they simply search for something that returned no results?). The result of that validation can then be passed to the Smarty template as an extra variable, and used to determine what messages need displaying.